# TakeUntil with Checkbox Blocks Stream Even When Evaluation is True

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to use `takeUntil` to stop a stream once a checkbox is switched off. I'm in Angular so for now I'm just concatenating a sting on a class property, not worrying about concatenating results of observables yet.

`this.checked$` is a `BehaviorSubject` that starts `false` and gets `next`ed when my checkbox is de/activated. That part is for sure working at least somewhat because below will start to display the dots. However, adding the (commented out below) `takeUntil(this.checked$)` results in no dots displaying at all.

```
const source$ = interval(250).pipe(mapTo("."));
this.checked$
.pipe(
  filter(c => {
    return c === true;
  }),
  switchMap(() => {
    console.log("switchMap");
    // return source$.pipe(takeUntil(this.checked$));
    return source$;
  })
)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log("in subscribe", data, this.dots);
  this.dots += data;
});
```

#### What is incorrect about how I am using `BehaviorSubject` and `takeUntil` here?

[Here is a full example is on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdacne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 2):

Note that `takeUntil` emits values only until the first `checked$` is emited, [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) are good examples. Because `checked$` is a `BehaviorSubject` it emits the current value immediately when you subscribe to it, as a result `takeUntil` stops.

A solution might be to switch between `source$` and an empty observable inside the switchMap, like:

```js
const source$ = interval(250).pipe(mapTo("."));
this.checked$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(c => {
      console.log("switchMap");
      return c ? source$ : EMPTY;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("in subscribe", data, this.dots);
    this.dots += data;
  });
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5oxkwv)

---

You can also fix your original solution by skipping the first value of `checked$` subject, but I recommend you the previous solution because it's simpler.

```js
const source$ = interval(250).pipe(mapTo("."));
this.checked$
  .pipe(
    filter(c => {
      return c === true;
    }),
    switchMap(() => {
      console.log("switchMap");
   // return source$.pipe(takeUntil(this.checked$));
      return source$.pipe(takeUntil(this.checked$.pipe(skip(1))));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("in subscribe", data, this.dots);
    this.dots += data;
  });
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bre9ae)

---

Another solution is to use [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) instead of [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject). The difference is that the `Subject` doesn't hold current value and emits nothing when you subscribe to it. It emits only when `next()` is called. If you replace `BehaviorSubject` with `Subject` in your original solution, it will work as expected.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzxy9n)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly when I say: `takeUntil` only obeys the first emission of a stream, and therefore the stream of alternating booleans my `checked$` emits is ignored after its first/initial `false` value. So the solution is not to give it immediate access to the stream but to alternate subscription/unsubscribtion based on `checked$`’s value. Have I got it?

Comment: @1252748 yes, it doesn't matter what value is emitted, `false` or even `undefined`, `takeUntil()` stops emission immediately when it receives that value. You can also fix the original solution by skipping that first value, I've added an example to the answer. I hope it will help you to figure out how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but here is what I don't understand. How come using `fromEvent` works? `https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-znpirx?file=index.ts` Here, checked should be an infinite boolean stream, no? What's the difference here. I have to use Subject here so I can control the emissions via an angular click. That's why I'm not using `fromEvent` in the first place. Also, FYI, this has all come from following this video: `https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-toggle-a-stream-on-and-off-with-rxjs`

Comment: @1252748 The difference is that `fromEvent` creates an observable that doesn't emit current value when you subscribe to it, while `BehaviorSubject` does. You can use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`. `Subject` doesn't hold the last emitted value so it will work like `fromEvent`, but it allows you to emit values manually via `next()` method. I'm sorry, I should have offered you this solution before. I've updated the answer too, hope it will help.